# Passing Server URL using Variable in Webserver connection manager

Tags: web-services, ssis

I m a newbie, learning SSIS. Currently I am trying to get data from webservice and import it to database table. When establishing the connection to the server. Is it possible to send it using variable instead of hardcoding it in HTTP connection manager Editior?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the connection manager and select "Parametrize". The rest of it should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more? I don't see any Parametrizing or Option to send variable in HTTP Connection Manager where we are suppose to give ServerURL to establish connection.